# ADF application deployed twice to run

Tags: java, oracle11g, oracle-adf

I am using jdeveloper Studio Edition Version 11.1.2.3.0
I have an ADF application deployed on Integrated web server.
every time when I run a any jsf page in the application, first time I have an error:
 Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxs.ww.rrn.view.utils.DocumentServlet
Remote deployment failed (oracle.jdevimpl.deploy.common.Jsr88RemoteDeployer
when I run for the second time the application run normally.

I have faced that in the system files:AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.3.39.62.76.1\system11.1.2.3.39.62.76.1\o.j2ee\drs\xx\xxViewControllerWebApp.war all java classes deleted for the first deployment, and show again in the second deployment.

can anyone help me?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

their's a diferrent between the package name in Model and ViewController, so when the app deployed, the ViewController package is not exist so all classes not be initiated.